# I'm trying to create an array which contains data from JSON but I get an empty array in the console

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to fetch some data using the AlphaVantage API and I would like to store all the dividends paid by a stock in an array.
I'm starting by only trying to save the dividends but in the future I would like to associate the dividend at a specific date.

**Function to retrieve the data:**

```
async function fetchTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted (ticker) {  //Fetch function to get the daily close and the dividends
    const apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${symbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`; //Lik of the API - update the symbol

    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted);
        const data = await response.json(); 
        const historicalDividend = []; //Array of the dividends
        
        for (let date in data['Time Series (Daily)']) { //This for should make the code go through all the JSON
            historicalDividend = entry ['7. dividend amount']; //This should store the dividend while the for loop "goes"
        }

        console.log(historicalDividend); //Console log to see the dividend

        return historicalDividend; //Value that the function must return
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted'); //Log of the error
    }
}
```

This is the function that I created but as I can see and probably you too it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to push into `historicalDividend`, not overwrite it.

Comment: `const historicalDividend = data['Time Series (Daily)'].map(entry => entry ['7. dividend amount'])`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare a variable `historicalDividend` and initialize it to an empty array, only to then re-assign the whole variable to the time series data, meaning you will override the value in every iteration. Also, `entry` is not defined, I think you meant to use `date` instead.

In order to address all those issues you should just use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which takes an array, loops over it and creates a new array with the return values of the callback.

As another tip: You should check the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the response to make sure you get the expected response.

Here a version of your code with both those issues addressed:

```js
async function fetchTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted(ticker) {
  //Fetch function to get the daily close and the dividends
  const apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${symbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`; //Lik of the API - update the symbol

  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted);
    // Check for HTTP response code
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(
        $`Fetching daily time series data failed with status code '${response.status}'`
      );
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const historicalDividend = data["Time Series (Daily)"].map(
      (entry) => entry["7. dividend amount"]
    );

    console.log(historicalDividend); //Console log to see the dividend

    return historicalDividend; //Value that the function must return
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching apiTimeSeriesDailyAdjusted"); //Log of the error
  }
}
```

> Your also now using the `ticker` parameter at the moment and symbol is not defined at least in the snippet your showing.